Constructing the Lie Quadric Using v-Asymptotic Tangent Lines
I am studying the geometric construction of the Lie quadric as outlined in a text, and I need some clarification on the process. The description is as follows:
''
The geometric definition is as follows. Along with point $ x(0,0) $ of $ M $, consider two points $ x(-\epsilon,0) $ and $ x(\epsilon,0) $. Let $ \eta, \eta_{-\epsilon}, \eta_{\epsilon} $ be the $ v $-asymptotic tangent lines at these points. These lines determine a quadric $ Q_{\epsilon} $, made of the lines, intersecting the three lines, and the quadric of Lie is the limiting position of $ Q_{\epsilon} $ as $ \epsilon \to 0  $. ''
To better understand this construction, I took the surface $ s $ defined by:
$ s(x, y)= xy + \frac{1}{3}(2x^3 + y^3) + x^4 $
I found that $ x(t) = \text{constant} $ is an asymptotic curve. The asymptotic lines through  the origin $ \eta, \eta_{\epsilon}, \eta_{-\epsilon} $ are given by:
$ \eta = (0, y, 0) $,
$ \eta_{\epsilon} = (x - \epsilon^2, y, z - \frac{2\epsilon^4}{3} + \epsilon^5 ) $ and
$ \eta_{-\epsilon} = (x - \epsilon^2, y, z - \frac{1}{3}\epsilon^4(2 + 3\epsilon) ) $
Additionally, I found the following equation in the book (see the image) $\textit{Projective Differential Geometry Old and New}$ by Ovsienko, which is supposed to represent the Lie quadric:
$ z = xy + \nu z^2 $
Here are my questions:

How exactly do these asymptotic lines define the quadric $ Q_{\epsilon} $?
What is the geometric intuition behind the quadric of Lie being the limiting position of $ Q_{\epsilon}$ as $ \epsilon $ approaches 0?

Any detailed explanation or references to similar constructions would be greatly appreciated!

